# Using ADB to install ARcore APK on adnroid

Tags: adb

trying to install the ARCore apk using adb on my S8+. Enabled USB debugging.

Used powershell on E:\Users\black\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools

then used ./adb shell to get 127|dream2lte:/

but when i run adb install -r -d arcore-preview.apk it gives the following error
/system/bin/sh: adb: not found.

any help will be appreciated, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was trying to run the command

```
adb install -r -d arcore-preview.apk
```

after having ran

```
adb shell
```

from Powershell. The latter command, in fact, places the user inside Android's own shell environment, as one can discern from `127|dream2lte:/`, which means that user `127` is currently logged in to the device `dream2lte`, and the working directory is Android's root `/`.

The solution was to run the first command only, entirely omitting the `adb shell` instruction, as the former is supposed to be issued from Powershell itself, which can be seen from the `adb install` portion of the instruction.